# NavigationBar text colour not changing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my `UITabBar` application I am adding `NavigationController` in each tab.
Suppose the selected index is 0 when I am opening the app.In my 3rd tab(selected index=2) I want to change the text colour of `navigationBar` title.And I am using the code

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [UIColor greenColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil]];
```

But its not changing the text color of Index 0 and 2.Colour of index 1 will change only if that tab was not clicked before changing the colour by using the above code.
I don't know whats is the issue ? Any help/code will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to do related `Navigationbar` title changes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Here you can set View width and height as per your requirement for displaying titleImageView position in navigationbar
    UIView *backView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];

    [backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UILabel *titleLbl =  [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 5, 180,30)];
    [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18.0f]];
    [titleLbl setText:@"Review Her"];
    titleLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [titleLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:230/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [backView addSubview:titleLbl];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = backView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler implementation would be to change the navigationBar's tintColor property on the UIViewController that is inside the UINavigationController of interest.

In your UIViewController, add the following line in one of the View Lifecycle methods:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```